# Is there software that can help high level management manage teams?

Tags: project-management, organizer-software

Is there software, preferably web-based, that can help high level management manage the tasks every team/department is working on?

E-mails don't cut it anymore...

Does SharePoint fit this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/tour/intranet-software.jsp), any other similar software like this?  It is wiki-based, super complex.

There's task based: http://www.gqueues.com/

There's http://backpackit.com/

Any other ones?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off starting by looking at the project management apps on the google marketplace. I've tried a few and although they didn't do what I needed, they may well fit your needs better.

Comment: thx, but no, we're not looking for Project Management, but thx for the Google Marketplace suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Our central IT org uses [TeamDynamix](http://www.teamdynamix.com/) which bills itself as "The Leader in Web-Based Project and Portfolio Management (PPM) Software".

My only knowledge of the system is from some of those tasked to use it whom find it a pain to log work towards projects...but I assume its not a tool issue but the process.  Also FWIW we have Confluence on campus and I believe that its mostly being phased out for SharePoint 2010.